# show my localhost in someother pc via ip

Tags: virtualhost

I have a site in my local which is running under `xampp`.Now in another `Mac` I want to access the local site.It can be done via sharing the ip? or something to write in host file.The source machine is windows and the target machine is mac.

I dont know how to include the ip in host file in `Mac`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's running on port 80 or 443 and your firewall is set to allow requests on those ports, you should be able to navigate to the ip address in a browser. If you're requesting your local site from outside your subnet then you might need to configure port forwarding on your router